# Symplectic leaves of a Poisson-Lie group are solutions of the associated bivector field.

Tags: symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

> Let $G$ be a Poisson-Lie group with the associated Poisson bivector field $\pi.$ Then it is well known that $\pi (e) = 0,$ where $e$ is the identity element in $G.$ Pavel Etingof mentioned in his lecture notes on compact quantum groups that $\{e\}$ is a symplectic leaf of $G.$

My question is $:$ How is symplectic leaf of a Poisson manifold defined?

Is it just the zeros of the bivector field associated with a Poisson manifold? In Chari and Pressley's book the definition of symplectic leaf is given in terms of an equivalence relation $\sim$ defined on the manifold such that $x \sim y$ if and only if there is a piecewise smooth path connecting $x$ and $y$ with each smooth piece of the path being a part of an integral curve of a Hamiltonian vector field defined on the underlying manifold. Could anyone please clarify it to me as to how are those two definitions equivalent? Any suggestion regarding this would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The symplectic leaves of a Poisson manifold are the submanifolds induced by integrating the Hamiltonian vector fields. Wikipedia has a good section about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold#Symplectic_leaves

Comment: @T.P.$:$ Then why are they solutions of the associated bivector field? Is it a consequence?

Comment: You mean zeros of the bivector field? By definition, the tangent space of a leaf at $x$ is the image of the map $\pi_x^\sharp:T_x^*M\to T_xM$. In case of zeros of $\pi$, this is the trivial vector space $\{0\}$. That means that the leaf is a $0$-dimensional submanifold that passes through $x$, hence $\{x\}$.

Comment: @T.P.$:$ I mean zeros of the associated bivector field.

Comment: @T.P.$:$ I don't get it. How is it related to the zeros of the bivector field then?

Comment: If $\pi_x=0$ then the image of the induced map at $x$ is $0$ and hence the tangent space of the leaf is the $0$-space.

Comment: In general every point lies on a leaf, but not all leaves are trivial. This happens for the zeros of the bivector field for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: @T.P.$:$ What is the definition of $\pi^{\sharp}\ $? Bivector fields are maps from $M \longrightarrow T^{\ast} M.$ Then what is meant by $\pi (v, \cdot)$ for $v \in T^{\ast} M.$ I am really confused at this stage.

Comment: @T.P.$:$ Do you have any idea about the following question $:$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4598662/778190

Answer (score 3):

Since the discussion in the comments got quite long, I summarize everything here.

---

### Poisson bivector fields and the map $\pi^\sharp$

A Poisson bivector field $\pi\in\mathfrak{X}^2(M):=\Gamma(\wedge^2TM)$ on a manifold $M$ is a smooth map $\pi:M\to\wedge^2TM$ (and not $M\to T^*M$ that you said). There is an induced vector bundle morphism $\pi^\sharp:T^*M\to TM$ over the identity on $M$ which, on the level of sections, is defined via
$$ \langle \alpha, \pi^\sharp(\beta) \rangle = \pi(\alpha,\beta),\qquad \text{for all } \alpha,\beta\in \Omega^1(M).$$
In terms of exact $1$-forms $df$ with $f\in  C^\infty(M)$, this map is given by $\pi^\sharp(df)=\{f,\cdot\}\in\mathfrak X(M)$; the Hamiltonian vector field of the function $f$ is defined to be that vector field $X_f:= \pi^\sharp(df)$.

### Hamiltonian distribution and symplectic leaves

The map $\pi^\sharp$ constructed above gives the (not necessarily regular) smooth distribution of the manifold $M$ spanned by the Hamiltonian vector fields. This distribution is closed under the Lie bracket of vector fields on $M$ due to one of the most fundamental identities of Poisson manifolds: $[X_f,X_g]=X_{\{f,g\}}$ for all smooth functions $f,g$ on $M$; that is, the distribution spanned by the Hamiltonian vector fields on $M$ is integrable, and hence can be integrated to a [foliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation#Foliation_definitions) on $M$. The leaves of this distribution are called *the symplectic leaves of the Poisson manifold $M$*. Note that, by definition, for any leaf $S$ passing through the point $x\in M$ we have $T_x S= \pi^\sharp_x(T_x^*M)\subset T_xM$.

In terms of the local Weinstein splitting, given the Darboux-Weinstein coordinates $(U,q^i,p^i,y^k)$ around a point $x$, where
$$\pi|_U=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial p^i} + \sum_{k,\ell} \pi’_{kl}(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} \wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial y^l}$$
with $\pi’(x)=0$, the symplectic leaf is described by the equations $y^k=0$ for all $k$.

Another more differential geometric way to view these leaves are, as you said, all the points that can be connected by pieces of flow curves of Hamiltonian vector fields, since they are precisely the submanifolds obtained by the span of all the Hamiltonian vector fields and, as a foliation, they are always connected.

More precisely, in the Darboux-Weinstein coordinates around $x\in M$ described above we can see that $X_{q^i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial p^i}$ and $X_{p^i}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}$, which means that the lines parallel to the axes are Hamiltonian flows. So we can connect any point in $S$ with the origin which corresponds to $x$ by projecting it onto the $q$-axis and then moving along the axis until we reach the origin. In the general case where two points are not in the same Darboux-Weinstein chart, we can connect them by finitely many charts of this form and proceed inductively.

Note that this idea has nothing to do with the Poisson structure, you can find more about it by looking up foliations/distributions on manifolds and the [Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) theorem for regular distributions. For singular distributions one needs the Stefan-Sussmann theorem; you can find a few things [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)#Singular_distributions), but it's still not a complete theory. I'm afraid I don't know of any elementary text for this. The only things I could suggest are either the original papers by Stefan and Sussmann (given in the Wikipedia article for singular distributions that I linked), or this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05386#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20Weinstein%20splitting,structure%20vanishes%20at%20the%20point.) (Corollary 3.14 and the comments right after that) from which I also learned about it when I was a student and it is Poisson-geometry-oriented.

### Zeros of the Poisson structure

Suppose that $x\in M$ is a zero of the Poisson bivector field, i.e. $\pi_x=0$. Then the tangent space of the leaf $S$ passing through $x$ is given by $T_x S=\pi^\sharp_x(T_x^*M)=\{0\}$. This implies that the dimension of the manifold $S$ is $0$, i.e. $S$ is a point. Since $x\in S$ we get that $S=\{x\}$.

In your case of the Poisson-Lie group $G$, this is applied to the identity element $e$ which is always a zero of its Poisson bivector field. And so $\{e\}$ is a symplectic leaf of $G$.

Comment: What is $\pi^{\sharp} (\beta)\ $? $\beta \in \Omega^{1} (M) \implies \beta_{x} \in T_{x}^{\ast} M \subset T^{\ast} M$ for any $x \in M.$ Also what is $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle\ $?

Comment: If the induced map on the level of sections be like $\pi^{\sharp} (\beta) (\alpha) = \pi (\alpha, \beta)$ then what's $\pi^{\sharp}$ on the level of bundles?

Comment: $\langle\cdot\,,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the pairing between a vector space and its dual; for the bundle map apply the map of sections point-wise.

Comment: Could you suggest some book where I can find such foliation stuffs? Wikipedia article is not good for first reading, I guess.

Comment: You argued that the distribution spanned by the Hamiltonian vector field is integrable but you didn't give any reason.

Comment: How do you define integrability of a distribution unless it has some fixed rank i.e. unless the distribution is regular?

Comment: As far as I have understood the distribution here is given by $\Delta_{x} = \pi_{x}^{\sharp} (T_{x}^{\ast} M)$ because for any $x \in M$ choose a coordinate chart $N_{x}, x_1,\cdots,x_n$ around $x$ such that $dx_1, \cdots, dx_n$ is a local frame of the cotangent bundle in $N_{x}.$ Let $y \in N_{x}$ and $v \in \Delta_{y}.$ Then there exists $\omega \in T_{y}^{\ast} M$ such that $\pi^{\sharp} (\omega) = v.$ Let $\omega = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} a_i dx_i(y).$ Then $v = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} a_i X_{x_i} (y).$ This shows that $\Delta_{y} = \text {span} \left \{X_{x_1}, \cdots, X_{x_n} \right \}.$

Comment: I mean $\Delta_y = \text {span} \left \{X_{x_1} (y), \cdots, X_{x_n} (y) \right \}.$ This is true for any $y \in N_{x}.$ But is it true that $T_y N_x = \Delta_y$ for all $y \in N_x\ ?$

Comment: My response was too long to fit in a comment so I edited the answer to include some references on singular distributions, not with an elementary approach, though. Perhaps if someone knows of any elementary text in this topic, they could write it here. But maybe the topic isn't elementary after all and so there isn't any elementary source to read about it from. Of course, in the special case of Poisson manifolds the Weinstein splitting gives the foliation as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: $:$ I will try to go through those paper. BTW could you please confirm whether my previous comments are on the right direction? You said that the distribution is integrable which means for every $x$ there should exist some submanifold $N_x \subseteq M$ containing $x$ such that for $y \in N_x$ we have $T_y N_x = \Delta_y.$ In this case I can take a frame coordinate chart around $x.$ If $X_{x_1} (y), \cdots, X_{x_n} (y)$ are linearly independent set of vectors for every $y$ in the frame coordinate chart then we are through. Otherwise how do I proceed?

Comment: Secondly, if such a thing happens to be true then what is the integrated foliation? What are the leaves? These are few of the questions which is not clear to me as I am a beginner of this topic. Many many thanks for your kind reply.